# on the outside or outside

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The playground is on the outside or it’s outside. Which is correct.?

Needed to say the location of places within the school.

Can I say the playground is on the outside when I’m in the classroom?

Answer (score 1):

The playground is *outside* the school.

*On the outside* usually means 'on the outer surface' of something.

> I wrote my name on the outside of the box.